# Basic file uploading fails

Tags: file-upload, playframework

I am not able to perform any uploading operations on the server. Contrary to "one of the five cool things you can do with play", the following does not seem to work:

```
    public static void doSingleFileUpload(
            Long id, @Required java.io.File upload,  String description, String title
            ) {
        Score score = Score.findById(id);

        try {
            score.files.add(new File(doFileUpload(new FileInputStream(upload), score), title));//PLAY crashes here, with a nullpointer exception on the upload parameter
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //TODO: do something nice
        }
        score.save();
    }
```

`doFileUpload` looks like this:

```
@Check("registered")
private static String doFileUpload(InputStream is, Score score) throws IOException {
    //get Score from db
    //get dir if present
    java.io.File dir = new java.io.File("/public/uploads/" + play.templates.JavaExtensions.slugify(score.title));
    //if not, create
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs(); //create new dir if not present
    }
    //create file on server
    java.io.File newfile = new java.io.File(dir, "testfile.txt");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
    IOUtils.copy(is, os);
    return newfile.getAbsolutePath();

}
```

With this view:

```
<!-- ... -->
    <form action="@{ScoreController.doSingleFileUpload()}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${score.id}" />
    <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" />
    <input type="text" name="description" />
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="${score.title}" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Why is `upload` null? I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863443/file-upload-in-playframework-with-different-browers). But when I look at the headers after the POST, there is very little information there, except for the playsession key...

What am I doing wrong?

I am testing with FF4 and using Play 1.1.1.

---

EDIT:
This sample application works in both 1.1.1 and 1.2.

Controller:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

public static void index() {
    File dir = new File(Play.applicationPath+File.separator+"public"+File.separator+"uploads");
    if (!dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
        renderText("something went wrong");
    } else {
        String[] files = dir.list();
        if (files != null) {
            render(dir);
        } else {
            render();
        }
    }
}

public static void upload(File upload) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File dir = new File(Play.applicationPath+File.separator+"public"+File.separator+"uploads");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    File newfile = new File(dir, upload.getName());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(upload);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
    IOUtils.copy(fis, fos);
    index();
}
```

}

View:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

#{form @Application.upload(), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
<input type="file" name="upload" />
<input type="submit" />
#{/form}
#{if (dir.list()!=null)}
<ul>
    #{list items:dir.list(), as:'file'}
    <li><a href="public/uploads/${file}">${file}</a></li>
    #{/list}
</ul>
#{/if}
```

Now the questions is: What is the difference between the applications, except for the fact that the first one has more parameters...

Thanks for the help everyone so far!

greetings,
jasper

Comment: what version of Play are you using, and what does the code look like for doFileUpload. If it is a public static, then your code will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have edited my post with an answer to your answer... It is not a public method, but that doesn't explain the `null` value from `upload`, or does it?

Answer (score 2):

Does that compile? You’re passing a `java.io.File` object to `doFileUpload`, whose first parameter is an `InputStream`.

Comment: This example is too complicated, i'm writing code as I'm looking at the answers, thus editing my post with different versions of the application. I'm going to edit my first post with a very simple file upload application. Thanks for your answer. Hope to hear from you soon!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your code is not working, but I got something similar to work by using Blob instead of File.

```
public static void update(long userId, 
                          String aboutMyself, 
                          String location, 
                          Blob profilePicBlob) {

    UserProfile userProfile = UserProfile.find("select distinct upr from UserProfile upr where upr.user.id = ?", userId).first();
    if(profilePicBlob != null) {
        //TODO: Delete the old profile pic
        userProfile.profilePic = new Pic(profilePicBlob).save();
    }
    userProfile.aboutMyself = aboutMyself;
    userProfile.location = location;
    userProfile.save();

    show(userId);
}

@Entity
public class Pic extends Model {
    public Blob image;

    public Pic(Blob image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}

#{form @UserProfileC.update(userProfile.user.id), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
    <div>
        <div>About Myself:</div>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80" name="aboutMyself">${userProfile.aboutMyself</textarea>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <div>Location</div>
        <input type="text" name="location" value="${userProfile.location}"/>
</div>
    <div>                   
        <input type="file" name="profilePicBlob" />
        <label>${userProfile.profilePic == null ? 'Upload' : 'Change'} profile pic</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="postComment" />
    </div>
#{/form}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciated! But I can't make any changes to the database structure at this stage in the development process. I'm not sure if I want to store all my binary files in the database as well... But I really appreciate your effort!